# Testdriven.io: Test-Driven Development with FastAPI and Docker Pytest in docker runs tests of env files

Tags: python, docker, pytest, fastapi, testdriven.io

I am following https://testdriven.io/courses/tdd-fastapi/pytest-setup/, but when running

```
docker-compose exec web python -m pytest
```

for the first time, I get

```
collected 212 items / 24 errors
```

instead of the expected 0 items.

The short test summary info shows among others

```
ERROR env/Lib/site-packages/h11/tests/test_against_stdlib_http.py
ERROR env/Lib/site-packages/h11/tests/test_connection.py
ERROR env/Lib/site-packages/h11/tests/test_events.py
ERROR env/Lib/site-packages/h11/tests/test_headers.py
```

so I believe my env folder in project is being copied in the container, however my .dockerignore file is present in project containing the following four lines:

```
env
.dockerignore
Dockerfile
Dockerfile.prod
```

I committed my current progress to this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/christophhillisch/TDD-FastApi/) ifyou want to take a look.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How's the file named? Is it `.env` or `env`?

Comment: The folder is named ```env```. I tried adding ```.env``` to the .dockerignore as well, but the behavior did not change.

Comment: I followed the same yesterday and was able to work as expected. Your code/Docker files look same, very strange why it's not working. I doubt these env files are from a virtual env of python (that is not shown in git because it was added to gitignore).

Comment: @ChristophH. are you mounting a `volume` containing the `env` folder?

Comment: Yes this was the problem. In the docker-compose I mount ```- ./project:/usr/src/app```. Deleting the env file from the container made the test work accordingly. Thanks @Isabi!

Comment: @ChristophH. I'm having a similar experience. Where did you delete the env file from? Which folder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the required "50 reputation" yet to comment so this has to be an "answer".

In the "getting started" section (https://testdriven.io/courses/tdd-fastapi/getting-started/), almost at the very end, there's a line "Exit then remove the virtual environment as well". Maybe you forgot to remove the virtual environment at that time? I'm not yet through the whole thing (actually, just starting the pytest setup), but I think the idea is to keep the volume with your source code mounted so that you can test from within the docker container.